# How to make your cordova android application run in background without using a android Service

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I am developing a cordova location application using the SimpleXpBeacon plugin and I have manged to run the my application in background for ios but, I am unable to run the application in background for Android. Can someone please help me out to run my application in the background. Here is the native android code provided by the Cordova SimplexpPlugin.
    package com.blackberry.community;

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015 BlackBerry Limited
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.LOG;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class SimpleXpBeaconPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleXpBeaconPlugin";

    private static final String PLUGIN_VERSION = "1.1.0";

    private static final String ACTION_INITIALISE_BLUETOOTH = "initialiseBluetooth";
    private static final String ACTION_TERMINATE_BLUETOOTH = "terminateBluetooth";
    private static final String ACTION_PLUGIN_VERSION = "pluginVersion";
    private static final String ACTION_START_MONITORING = "startMonitoring";
    private static final String ACTION_STOP_MONITORING = "stopMonitoring";
    private static final String ACTION_ADD_BEACON_UUID_TO_MONITOR = "addBeaconUuidToMonitor";
    private static final String ACTION_REMOVE_BEACON_UUID_TO_MONITOR = "removeBeaconUuidToMonitor";

    private static final String JSON_KEY_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION = "desc";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_ERROR_CODE = "error_code";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_EVENT = "event";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_PLUGIN_VERSION = "plugin_version";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_DATA = "data";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_IBEACON_UUID = "uuid";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_IBEACON_MAJOR = "major";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_IBEACON_MINOR = "minor";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_IBEACON_RSSI = "rssi";
    private static final String JSON_KEY_IBEACON_TXPOWER = "txpower";

    private static final String JSON_VALUE_ERROR = "ERROR";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_OK = "OK";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_STARTED = "STARTED";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_IBEACON = "IBEACON";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION = "Plugin Version";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_NO_BT_LE_FEATURE = "This device doesn't have BT LE feature";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_NO_BT_ADAPTER = "Unable to obtain Bluetooth Adapter";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_BT_ALREADY_INITIALISED = "Bluetooth already initialised";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_BT_NOT_INITIALISED = "Bluetooth not initialised";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_BT_INITIALISED = "Bluetooth initialised";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_BT_TERMINATE = "Bluetooth Terminated";
    private static final int JSON_VALUE_DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE = -1;
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_ALREADY_MONITORING_FOR_I_BEACONS = "Already monitoring for iBeacons";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_FAILED_TO_ENABLE_MONITORING = "Failed to enable iBeacon monitoring";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_NOT_MONITORING = "Not monitoring for iBeacons";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_FAILED_TO_DISABLE_MONITORING = "Failed to Disable Monitoring";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_STOPPED_MONITORING = "Stopped Monitoring for iBeacons OK";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_REQUESTED_MONITORING = "Requested iBeacon Monitoring OK";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_IBEACON_EVENT = "iBeacon event";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_IMPROPER_FORMAT = "UUID was improper format";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_NULL = "UUID was null";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_UUID_ADDED = "UUID added";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_IBEACON_ALREADY_BEING_MONITORED = "iBeacon already being monitored";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_BEACON_REMOVED = "iBeacon UUID removed successfully";
    private static final String JSON_VALUE_NO_MATCH_TO_BEACON_UUID = "iBeacon UUID did not match any being monitored";

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mBtInitialised = false;
    private boolean mMonitoring = false;
    private CallbackContext mMonitoringCallbackContext;
    private List<UUID> mBeaconRegionsToMonitor;
    private boolean mSupressMonitorCallback = false;

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
                    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Device Address: " + device.getAddress().toString());
                            Log.d(TAG, "RSSI: " + rssi);
                            BeaconData beaconData = new BeaconData(scanRecord);
                            if (beaconData.hasIBeaconData()) {

                                boolean isEmpty = true;
                                boolean containsUuid = true;

                                synchronized(SimpleXpBeaconPlugin.this) {
                                    isEmpty = mBeaconRegionsToMonitor.isEmpty();
                                    containsUuid = mBeaconRegionsToMonitor.contains(beaconData.uuid());
                                }
                                if (!isEmpty && !containsUuid) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Skipping notification of UUID: " + beaconData.uuid().toString());
                                    return;
                                }

                                Log.d(TAG, "TxPowerLevel: " + beaconData.txPowerLevel());
                                Log.d(TAG, "Major: " + beaconData.major());
                                Log.d(TAG, "Minor: " + beaconData.minor());
                                Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + beaconData.uuid().toString());

                                JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
                                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

                                try {
                                    data.put(JSON_KEY_IBEACON_UUID, beaconData.uuid().toString());
                                    data.put(JSON_KEY_IBEACON_MAJOR, beaconData.major());
                                    data.put(JSON_KEY_IBEACON_MINOR, beaconData.minor());
                                    data.put(JSON_KEY_IBEACON_RSSI, rssi);
                                    data.put(JSON_KEY_IBEACON_TXPOWER, beaconData.txPowerLevel());

                                    response.put(JSON_KEY_STATUS, JSON_VALUE_OK);
                                    response.put(JSON_KEY_EVENT, JSON_VALUE_IBEACON);
                                    response.put(JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION, JSON_VALUE_IBEACON_EVENT);
                                    response.put(JSON_KEY_DATA, data);

                                    if (!isSupressMonitorCallback()) {
                                        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, response.toString());
                                        result.setKeepCallback(true);
                                        getMonitoringCallbackContext().sendPluginResult(result);
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "JSON Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        LOG.d(TAG, "in initialize");
        mBeaconRegionsToMonitor =  new ArrayList<UUID>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        LOG.d(TAG, "requested action = " + action);

        boolean validAction = false;

        if (action.equals(ACTION_INITIALISE_BLUETOOTH)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Initialise Bluetooth request");

            validAction = true;

            if (!deviceHasBtLeFeature()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_NO_BT_LE_FEATURE);
                return validAction;
            }

            if (isBtInitialised()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BT_ALREADY_INITIALISED);
                return validAction;
            }

            BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                    (BluetoothManager) cordova.getActivity()
                            .getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_NO_BT_ADAPTER);
                return validAction;
            }

            successResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BT_INITIALISED);
            setBtInitialised(true);
            return validAction;

        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_TERMINATE_BLUETOOTH)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Terminate Bluetooth request");

            validAction = true;

            if (!isBtInitialised()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BT_NOT_INITIALISED);
                return validAction;
            }

            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            mBluetoothAdapter = null;

            successResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BT_TERMINATE);
            setBtInitialised(false);
            return validAction;

        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_PLUGIN_VERSION)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Plugin Version request");

            validAction = true;

            pluginVersionResponse(callbackContext, PLUGIN_VERSION);
            return validAction;

        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_START_MONITORING)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Start Monitoring request");
            validAction = true;

            if (!isBtInitialised()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BT_NOT_INITIALISED);
                return validAction;
            }

            if (isMonitoring()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_ALREADY_MONITORING_FOR_I_BEACONS);
                return validAction;
            }

            if (!enableMonitoring(callbackContext)) {
                monitorFailResponse(callbackContext);
                return validAction;
            }

            setSupressMonitorCallback(false);
            monitorSuccessResponse(callbackContext);
            return validAction;

        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_STOP_MONITORING)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Stop Monitoring request");
            validAction = true;

            if (!isBtInitialised()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BT_NOT_INITIALISED);
                return validAction;
            }

            if (!isMonitoring()) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_NOT_MONITORING);
                return validAction;
            }

            if (!disableMonitoring(callbackContext)) {
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_FAILED_TO_DISABLE_MONITORING);
                return validAction;
            }

            successResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_STOPPED_MONITORING);
            return validAction;

        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_ADD_BEACON_UUID_TO_MONITOR)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Add Beacon to Monitor request");
            validAction = true;
            UUID beaconRegionUuid;

            try {
                beaconRegionUuid = UUID.fromString(args.getString(0));

                if (!mBeaconRegionsToMonitor.contains(beaconRegionUuid)) {
                    synchronized(SimpleXpBeaconPlugin.this) {
                        mBeaconRegionsToMonitor.add(beaconRegionUuid);
                    }
                    successResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_UUID_ADDED);
                } else {
                    errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_IBEACON_ALREADY_BEING_MONITORED);
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOG.d(TAG, "" + JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_NULL);
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_NULL);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                LOG.d(TAG, "" + JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_IMPROPER_FORMAT);
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_IMPROPER_FORMAT);
            }
            return validAction;

        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_REMOVE_BEACON_UUID_TO_MONITOR)) {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Processing Remove Beacon to Monitor request");
            validAction = true;
            UUID beaconRegionUuid;
            boolean removed = false;

            try {
                beaconRegionUuid = UUID.fromString(args.getString(0));

                synchronized(SimpleXpBeaconPlugin.this) {;
                    removed = mBeaconRegionsToMonitor.remove(beaconRegionUuid);
                }

                if (removed) {
                    successResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_BEACON_REMOVED);
                } else {
                    errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_NO_MATCH_TO_BEACON_UUID);
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOG.d(TAG, "" + JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_NULL);
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_NULL);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                LOG.d(TAG, "" + JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_IMPROPER_FORMAT);
                errorResponse(callbackContext, JSON_VALUE_UUID_WAS_IMPROPER_FORMAT);
            }
            return validAction;

        } else {

            LOG.d(TAG, "Unmatched action" + action);
            validAction = false;
        }

        return validAction;
    }

    private boolean enableMonitoring(CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        boolean rc = true;

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback)) {
            setMonitoring(true);
            setMonitoringCallbackContext(callbackContext);
        } else {
            setMonitoring(false);
            rc = false;
        }
        return rc;
    }

    private boolean disableMonitoring(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        setMonitoring(false);
        setMonitoringCallbackContext(null);
        return true;
    }

    private void pauseMonitoring() {
        if (isMonitoring()) {
            setSupressMonitorCallback(true);
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    private void resumeMonitoring() {
        if (isMonitoring()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            setSupressMonitorCallback(false);
        }
    }

    private void pluginVersionResponse(CallbackContext callbackContext, String version) throws JSONException {

        // {"desc":"Plugin Version","plugin_version":"1.0.0","status":"OK"}

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put(JSON_KEY_PLUGIN_VERSION, version);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION, JSON_VALUE_PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_STATUS, JSON_VALUE_OK);
        callbackContext.success(response.toString());
    }

    private void successResponse(CallbackContext callbackContext, String description) throws JSONException {

        // {"desc":"...","status":"OK"}

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put(JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_STATUS, JSON_VALUE_OK);
        callbackContext.success(response.toString());
    }

    private void monitorSuccessResponse(CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        // {"desc":"...","status":"OK"}

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put(JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION, JSON_VALUE_REQUESTED_MONITORING);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_STATUS, JSON_VALUE_OK);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_EVENT, JSON_VALUE_STARTED);

        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, response.toString());
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
    }

    private void monitorFailResponse(CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        // {"desc":"...","status":"ERROR", "error_code": nnn, "event":"STARTED"}

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put(JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION, JSON_VALUE_FAILED_TO_ENABLE_MONITORING);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_STATUS, JSON_VALUE_ERROR);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_ERROR_CODE, JSON_VALUE_DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_EVENT, JSON_VALUE_STARTED);
        callbackContext.success(response.toString());
    }

    private void errorResponse(CallbackContext callbackContext, String description) throws JSONException {

        // {"desc":"...","status":"ERROR", "error_code": nnn}

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put(JSON_KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_STATUS, JSON_VALUE_ERROR);
        response.put(JSON_KEY_ERROR_CODE, JSON_VALUE_DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE);
        callbackContext.success(response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        LOG.d(TAG, "In onDestroy()");

        if (isMonitoring()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            setMonitoring(false);

        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter = null;
            setBtInitialised(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(boolean multitasking) {
        super.onPause(multitasking);
        LOG.d(TAG, "In onPause()");
        pauseMonitoring();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
        super.onResume(multitasking);
        LOG.d(TAG, "In onResume()");
        resumeMonitoring();


    }


    private boolean deviceHasBtLeFeature() {
        boolean rc = false;
        if (cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            rc = true;
        }
        return rc;
    }

    public boolean isSupressMonitorCallback() {
        return mSupressMonitorCallback;
    }

    public void setSupressMonitorCallback(boolean supressMonitorCallback) {
        this.mSupressMonitorCallback = supressMonitorCallback;
    }

    private boolean isBtInitialised() {
        return mBtInitialised;
    }

    private void setBtInitialised(boolean btInitialised) {
        this.mBtInitialised = btInitialised;
    }

    private boolean isMonitoring() {
        return mMonitoring;
    }

    private void setMonitoring(boolean monitoring) {
        this.mMonitoring = monitoring;
    }


    private CallbackContext getMonitoringCallbackContext() {
        return mMonitoringCallbackContext;
    }

    private void setMonitoringCallbackContext(CallbackContext monitoringCallbackContext) {
        this.mMonitoringCallbackContext = monitoringCallbackContext;
    }

    private class BeaconData {

        private byte[] mScanData;
        private int mMajor = 0;
        private int mMinor = 0;
        private int mTxPowerLevel = 0;
        private UUID mUuid;
        private boolean mHasIBeaconData = false;

        public BeaconData(byte[] scanData) {
            this.mScanData = scanData.clone();
            parseScanData();
        }

        private void parseScanData() {

            mHasIBeaconData = false;

            if (mScanData.length < 27) {
                return;
            }

            byte[] beaconUuid = new byte[16];
            byte[] beaconUuidLowHalf = new byte[beaconUuid.length/2];
            byte[] beaconUuidHighHalf = new byte[beaconUuid.length/2];
            long beaconUuidLeastSig = 0;
            long beaconUuidMostSig = 0;

            int i = 0;
            int entryLen = 0;
            int entryType = 0;
            do {
                entryLen = mScanData[i];
                entryType = mScanData[i+1];

                if ((entryType & 0xff) == 0xff) {
                    int j = i+2;
                    if ((mScanData[j] == 0x4c) && (mScanData[j+1] == 0x00) &&
                            (mScanData[j+2] == 0x02) && (mScanData[j+3] == 0x15)) {


                        mHasIBeaconData = true;
                        for (int k=0; k<beaconUuid.length; k++) {
                            beaconUuid[k] = mScanData[k+j+4];
                        }
                        j += (beaconUuid.length + 4);
                        mMajor = 0;
                        mMajor = (mScanData[j+1] & 0xff);
                        mMajor += ((mScanData[j] & 0xff) << 8);
                        j += 2;
                        mMinor = 0;
                        mMinor = (mScanData[j+1] & 0xff);
                        mMinor += ((mScanData[j] & 0xff) << 8);
                        j += 2;
                        mTxPowerLevel = ((-1 << 8) & 0xffffff00);
                        mTxPowerLevel += (mScanData[j] & 0xff);
                    }
                }
                i += (entryLen+1);
            } while (i < mScanData.length && entryLen != 0 );

            if (mHasIBeaconData) {
                for (i=0; i < (beaconUuidLowHalf.length); i++) {
                    beaconUuidHighHalf[i] = beaconUuid[i];
                    beaconUuidLowHalf[i] = beaconUuid[i + beaconUuidLowHalf.length];
                }
                beaconUuidLeastSig = bytesToLong(beaconUuidLowHalf);
                beaconUuidMostSig = bytesToLong(beaconUuidHighHalf);
                mUuid = new UUID(beaconUuidMostSig, beaconUuidLeastSig);
            }
        }

        private long bytesToLong(byte[] b) {
            long result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                result <<= 8;
                result |= (b[i] & 0xFF);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public boolean hasIBeaconData() {
            return mHasIBeaconData;
        }

        public int txPowerLevel() {
            return mTxPowerLevel;
        }

        public int major() {
            return mMajor;
        }

        public int minor() {
            return mMinor;
        }

        public UUID uuid() {
            return mUuid;
        }
    }
}

Do I need to use the android service to run my application in background?
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this plugin work for background process the config.xml should always be in running state. Remove the onPause() and onResume() methods from the above code. It works perfectly for me. For more details follow this link
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/config.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your app running in background mode, try using the [Background Mode plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode). Note, I wouldn't use this on iOS since Apple may reject your binary.